# ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 form always null on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have multiple forms in a razor view. The forms are created dynamically based on database values. Now when I post a form to server I always get empty list but validation is working. Here is my code:

**View**

```
<form id="@distinc[i].CategoryName.Replace(" ", string.Empty)" asp-action="Report" asp-controller="Laboratory">

@{
var obj = (List<ReportModel>)ViewBag.ReportModel;
var distinct = obj.DistinctBy(m => m.CategoryName).ToList();

@for (int i = 0; i < distinct.Count(); i++)
{
    <form id="@distinc[i].CategoryName.Replace(" ", string.Empty)" asp-action="Report" asp-controller="Laboratory">

        @{
            var items = obj.Where(m => m.CategoryName == distinc[i].CategoryName).ToList();
        }
        <div class="row g-3">
            @for (int k = 0; k < items.Count(); k++)
            {
                <input asp-for="@items[k].RequestId" hidden />
                <input asp-for="@items[k].ServiceName" hidden />
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-0 pb-0 mb-0 mt-0">
                    <label class="form-label">@items[k].ServiceName</label>
                    <input asp-for="@items[k].Result" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@items[k].Result" class="small text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-3 border-0">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

**Actions**

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Report(int id)
{
    var model = await laboratoryRepository.GetRequests(id);
    ViewBag.ReportModel = model;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Report(List<ReportModel> model)
{
        
}
```

**Model Class**

```cs
public class ReportModel : PatientInfo
{
    public long RequestId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

I tried using `[FromForm]` attribute but no luck. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make parameters name consistent. Change `model` to `items`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Report(List<ReportModel> items)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot post `list of model` in mvc

```c#
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Report(ReportModel model)
{
        
}
```